# store() method does not perform the registration of a record in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

When registering a record in my form from the file `create_blade.php` the page is redirected to the `index.blade.php` (which in this case is like `'/'`), but **the record does not appear on this page where there is the existence of a table that lists the records**.

- `create_blade.php`

```
    <form action="{{ url("create") }}" method="POST">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          ...
    </form>
```

- `web.php`

```
    Route::controller(HunterController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'index');
        Route::get('/create', 'create');
        Route::get('/update/{id}', 'edit');
        Route::post('create', 'store');
        Route::patch('/update/{id}', 'update');
        Route::delete('/delete/{id}', 'destroy'); 
    });
```

- `HunterModel.php`

```
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "hunter";
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    const CREATED_AT = 'date_register';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'date_update';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name_hunter',
        'year_hunter',
        'height_hunter',
        'weight_hunter',
        'type_hunter',
        'type_nen',
        'type_blood'
    ];
```

- `HunterController.php`

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validate(
        [
            'name_hunter' => 'required|max:50',
            'year_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'height_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'weight_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'type_hunter' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_nen' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_blood' => 'required|max:3',
        ]);
        HunterModel::saved($validations);
        return redirect()->to('/'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you confused `::saved()` - event method that's fired when element is created/updated with `::create()` method, that creates a record.

if you replace `saved` with `create` in `HunterController::store`, it will create a new record.

btw check out [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers), that's a lot more convenient way to create generic controllers like this.